# how to use python coding to download files on a web with following source(parts of the page)

Tags: javascript, python, web, download, embeddedwebserver

I want to download some public files from a web which include some javascript code in it to make user to interactively click to download. So it is not easy to scrap the download link directly. 
Actually this web is the newly pop-up website when I click the previous website. The previous website have the similar table while not have the files but the "button" to lead to this website which have the following source contents:

Code :-

```
    <table class="Grid" cellspacing="0" rules="all" border="1" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_plc1Content_ucGISExternalSearchResultsView_ucView_ucWIDFolderListView_grdList" style="width:100%;border-collapse:collapse;">
        <tr class="GridHeader">
            <th scope="col" style="width:2%;white-space:nowrap;">Open</th><th scope="col">Data Type</th><th scope="col">Direction</th><th scope="col">Data Date</th><th scope="col">Create Date</th><th scope="col">File</th><th scope="col">File Name</th><th scope="col" style="white-space:nowrap;">File Size</th>
        </tr><tr class="GridItem" onmouseover="this.className='highlightrow'" onmouseout="this.className=''">
            <td align="center" style="white-space:nowrap;">
                    <***input onclick="javascript: if(!PerformConfirm('Are you sure you want to download the file 87K193-Cut_and_Cap.pdf?***')) return false; else return true ;" type="submit" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$plc1Content$ucGISExternalSearchResultsView$ucView$ucWIDFolderListView$grdList$ctl03$btnDownload" value="" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_plc1Content_ucGISExternalSearchResultsView_ucView_ucWIDFolderListView_grdList_ctl03_btnDownload" title="Download" class="SelectButton" /> 
                </td><td align="center">DRILLING &amp; COMPLETION</td><td align="center">&nbsp;</td><td align="center">2012-10-03</td><td align="center">2012-10-03</td><td align="center">PDF</td><td align="center">87K193-Cut_and_Cap.pdf</td><td align="center">
                    <span id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_plc1Content_ucGISExternalSearchResultsView_ucView_ucWIDFolderListView_grdList_ctl03_lblFileSize">69 KB</span>
                </td>
        </tr><tr class="GridAlternatingItem" onmouseover="this.className='highlightrow'" onmouseout="this.className=''">
            <td align="center" style="white-space:nowrap;">
                    <input onclick="javascript: if(!PerformConfirm('Are you sure you want to download the file 87k193_ER130_V.PDF?')) return false; else return true ;" type="submit" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$plc1Content$ucGISExternalSearchResultsView$ucView$ucWIDFolderListView$grdList$ctl04$btnDownload" value="" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_plc1Content_ucGISExternalSearchResultsView_ucView_ucWIDFolderListView_grdList_ctl04_btnDownload" title="Download" class="SelectButton" /> 
                </td><td align="center">DRILLING &amp; COMPLETION</td><td align="center">&nbsp;</td><td align="center">2012-10-03</td><td align="center">2012-10-03</td><td align="center">PDF</td><td align="center">87k193_ER130_V.PDF</td><td align="center">
                    <span id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_plc1Content_ucGISExternalSearchResultsView_ucView_ucWIDFolderListView_grdList_ctl04_lblFileSize">715 KB</span>
                </td>
        </tr><tr class="GridItem" onmouseover="this.className='highlightrow'" onmouseout="this.className=''">
            <td align="center" style="white-space:nowrap;">
                    <input onclick="javascript: if(!PerformConfirm('Are you sure you want to download the file 87K193_Survey_Plan.pdf?')) return false; else return true ;" type="submit" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$plc1Content$ucGISExternalSearchResultsView$ucView$ucWIDFolderListView$grdList$ctl05$btnDownload" value="" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_plc1Content_ucGISExternalSearchResultsView_ucView_ucWIDFolderListView_grdList_ctl05_btnDownload" title="Download" class="SelectButton" /> 
                </td><td align="center">SURVEY PLANS &amp; DR SURVEYS</td><td align="center">&nbsp;</td><td align="center">2011-06-14</td><td align="center">2011-06-14</td><td align="center">PDF</td><td align="center">87K193_Well_Survey_Plan.pdf</td><td align="center">
                    <span id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_plc1Content_ucGISExternalSearchResultsView_ucView_ucWIDFolderListView_grdList_ctl05_lblFileSize">33 KB</span>
                </td>
        </tr><tr class="GridRowCount">
            <td class="GridRowCount" colspan="8">3 data records found.</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: I think this phenomena is very popular in odd style gov websites. If you need more information on the source code of the website, please let me know.

Comment: Have you tried using selenium?

Comment: @Alex Hail. I am a new coder and learning selenium this afternoon. Trying to figure out how to do it with selenium. Always error when running examples:(